# Oracle SQL lead lag across different group

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Suppose I have the below table. They key is just concat P1, P2, P3. I want to compare between key for each day. for example, from day 1 to day2, abc is removed and abe, aby is added.

```
P1  P2  P3  DAY KEY

a   b   c   1   abc
a   b   e   2   abe
a   b   y   2   aby
a   b   x   3   abx
a   b   c   3   abc
```

Expected result set:

```
KEY OPERATION DAY

abc  ADD      1
abe  ADD      2
aby  ADD      2
abc  REMOVE   2
abx  ADD      3
abc  ADD      3
abe  REMOVE   3
aby  REMOVE   3
```

And what if the day is not sequential. For example:

```
P1  P2  P3  DAY  KEY

a   b   c   1    abc
a   b   e   2    abe
a   b   y   2    aby
a   b   x   5    abx
a   b   c   5    abc
```

And the expected result is:

```
KEY OPERATION DAY

abc  ADD      1
abe  ADD      2
aby  ADD      2
abc  REMOVE   2
abx  ADD      5
abc  ADD      5
abe  REMOVE   5
aby  REMOVE   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `lag()` and `lead()`. The idea is to compare the previous and following date value for each key, and use that to identify the date when a key was added or removed - this assumes that `day` is a number that increments sequentially, without gaps.

```
with cte as (
    select
        t.*,
        lag(day) over(partition by p1, p2, p3 order by day) lag_day,
        lead(day) over(partition by p1, p2, p3 order by day) lead_day
    from mytable t
)
select p1, p2, p3, day, 'add' event
from cte
where lag_day is null or lag_day <> day - 1 
union all
select p1, p2, p3, day + 1, 'remove'
from cte
where lead_day is null or lead_day <> day + 1 
order by day, p1, p2, p3
```

With your sample data in **[this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b1a9fe671e0403f816ab480bec9c69cc)**, this produces:

```
P1 | P2 | P3 | DAY | EVENT 
:- | :- | :- | --: | :-----
a  | b  | c  |   1 | add   
a  | b  | c  |   2 | remove
a  | b  | e  |   2 | add   
a  | b  | y  |   2 | add   
a  | b  | c  |   3 | add   
a  | b  | e  |   3 | remove
a  | b  | x  |   3 | add   
a  | b  | y  |   3 | remove
a  | b  | c  |   4 | remove
a  | b  | x  |   4 | remove
```

This seems more complete that your expected results. Note that all records still available on the last date appear as removed on the following (hypothetical) day - this seems consistent with the fact that all new records appear as added on the first day.

I did not use the pseudo-key, because it don't see how it helps - and, if the values had more than one character, it could lead into trouble by creating "false" duplicates.

Comment: I think this is awesome. Actually in reality, it has gap between days. I am thinking need to rank the days first and then lead lap on the rank? For example, day 2 can have multiple timestamp with different keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without window functions, if you want:

```
select key, 'add', day
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.key = t.key and t2.day = t.day - 1
                 )
union all
select key, 'remove', day + 1
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.key = t.key and t2.day = t.day + 1
                 )
```