# Oracle SQL Lead Lag across group for historical data

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121770/oracle-sql-lead-lag-across-different-group). Suppose I have below table structure. P1, P2, P3 those 3 attributes represent as a key. I want to compare each key for each day. for example, from day 1 to day2, abc is removed and abe, aby is added.

```
P1  P2  P3  DAY  KEY

a   b   c   1    abc
a   b   e   2    abe
a   b   y   2    aby
a   b   x   5    abx
a   b   c   5    abc
```

I am thinking to generate a result set which has start / end date to track history. The expected result set:

```
P1  P2  P3      KEY  STARTTIME  ENDTIME

a   b   c       abc     1         2
a   b   e       abe     2         5
a   b   y       aby     2         5
a   b   x       abx     5        NULL
a   b   c       abc     5        NULL
```

Thanks for providing help for my previous post. I modified one of the answers as below to get add/remove result set but still not able to convert to above start/end time model.

```
with base as (
select
    'a' as p1,
    'b' as p2,
    'c' as p3,
    1 as day
from dual
union
select
    'a' as p1,
    'b' as p2,
    'y' as p3,
    2 as day
from dual
union
select
    'a' as p1,
    'b' as p2,
    'e' as p3,
    2 as day
from dual
union
select
    'a' as p1,
    'b' as p2,
    'x' as p3,
    5 as day
from dual
union
select
    'a' as p1,
    'b' as p2,
    'c' as p3,
    5 as day
from dual
),
calendar as (
select
    day,
    lead(day) over (order by day asc) as nextday,
    lag(day) over (order by day asc) as prevday
from
    (select distinct day from base)
),
data as (
    select
        p1,
        p2,
        p3,
        base.day,
        lead(base.day) over (partition by p1, p2, p3 order by base.day asc) as nextrow,
        lag(base.day) over (partition by p1, p2, p3 order by base.day asc) as prevrow,
        calendar.nextday,
        calendar.prevday
    from 
        base
    left join
        calendar
            on calendar.day = base.day
)
select * from data
/

select
    d1.p1,
    d1.p2,
    d1.p3,
    d1.day,
    d1.nextrow,
    d1.prevrow,
    'ADD' as op,
    d1.day as d
from 
    data d1
where
    prevrow is null or prevrow <> prevday
union
select
    d2.p1,
    d2.p2,
    d2.p3,
    d2.day,
    d2.nextrow,
    d2.prevrow,
    'REMOVE' as op,
    nextday
from 
    data d2
where
    nextrow is null or nextrow <> nextday
order by
    d, op asc
```

Comment: What's the point of the `KEY` column? If it is just a concatenation of `(P1, P2, P3)`, then leave it alone; you don't need it (even if you think you do), and it will eventually get you in trouble.

Comment: Also, none of the "key" combinations appear for DAY=3; doesn't that mean they all ended on DAY=2 (or earlier)? If not, why not? I don't see an explanation of that in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this as a gaps-and-island problem. You can use the difference between row numbers to identify groups of adjacent records. To compute the `end_day`, a little more logic is needed, since days are not sequential: I used a window `sum()` that increases when the date changes and `first_value()` to get the actual "next" date:

```
select 
    p1, 
    p2,
    p3,
    min(day) over(partition by p1, p2, p3, rn1 - rn2 order by day) start_day,
    case 
        when min(day) over(partition by p1, p2, p3, rn1 - rn2 order by day) 
            <> max(lead_day) over()
        then max(lead_day) over(partition by day_grp) 
    end end_day
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when day = lead_day then 0 else 1 end) over(order by day) day_grp
    from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by day) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by p1, p2, p3 order by day) rn2,
        lead(day) over(order by day) lead_day
    from mytable t
    ) t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9a7e8d90a32c8b16d8d4560e473c44cd)**:

```
P1 | P2 | P3 | START_DAY | END_DAY
:- | :- | :- | --------: | ------:
a  | b  | c  |         1 |       2
a  | b  | e  |         2 |       5
a  | b  | y  |         2 |       5
a  | b  | x  |         5 |    null
a  | b  | c  |         5 |    null
```